# ошибка request_callback_answer

Tags: python, pyrogram

Я столкнулся с проблемой при использовании библиотеки Pyrogram в Python для нажатия на кнопку в мессенджере. Когда я пытаюсь через скрипт используя request_callback_answer нажать на кнопку(берем в пример бота с кнопками BFG) то первое нажатие проходит как надо, на второе нажатие удаляется сообщение с кнопками, а если взять бота OneHassel_bot то у него при нажатии на кнопку редактируется сообщение и при этом кнопки и message_id остаются прежние но я получаю ошибку Requests timed out.

Я проверил свое соединение с Интернетом и убедился, что оно стабильно. Также я прочитал документацию Pyrogram и примеры кода, но не нашел решения для этой проблемы.

Мой код выглядит примерно так:

```py
def start_farm(client, message, stop_event, prefix):
    a = 0
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        for i in range(0, 100000):
            print(i)
            try:
                try:
                    client.request_callback_answer(
                        chat_id=message.chat.id,
                        message_id = int(data_test["id"]),
                        callback_data = data_test["Buttons_callback"][i],
                    )
                    time.sleep(int(data_test["Timeout"]))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    a = a+1
                    break
            except IndexError:
                break
            break

        if a == 1:
            message.edit(f"[{prefix}] произошла ошибка, фарм завершил работу")
            break
        time.sleep(int(data_test["Timeout"]))
```

Может ли кто-то помочь мне разобраться в этой проблеме? Я буду благодарен за любую информацию или совет который поможет мне успешно использовать скрипт для нажатия на кнопки через библиотеку Pyrogram.

Спасибо заранее за вашу помощь!

P.S. Я использую версию Pyrogram 2.0.106 и Python 3.8.0 на операционной системе Windows 7.

Я проверил свое соединение с Интернетом и убедился, что оно стабильно. Также я прочитал документацию Pyrogram и примеры кода, но не нашел решения для этой проблемы.